# Linear data processing to simultaneous processing

Tags: python, multithreading, iterator, multiprocessing, generator

I'm trying to understand multiprocessing. Let's say that I have a fairly large number of values between 0 and 1 stored in a list.

```
a = [rand() for _ in range(1e9)]
```

And I want to do something if the value is higher than 0.5.

```
for i in a:
    if i > 0.5:
        do_something()
```

Each value will thus be evaluated linearly. But can I evaluate several values simultaneously?

```
is_above = (i for i in a if i > 0.5)

import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool()
task = pool.imap(do_something, is_above, chunksize=1e9/4) # 1e9 elements divided by 4 cores?
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Will this piece of code work as expected?

Edit:
Here is a concrete example, with prime numbers :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def is_prime(num):
    if num > 2:
        for i in range(2, num // 2):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)


start = 1_000_000_000
stop = 1_000_000_500
a = (i for i in range(start, stop))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool()
    t = p.imap(is_prime, a, chunksize=int((stop - start) / 6)) #6 cores
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I think anyone interested in this should read this before :
https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-ece023ad55a

Comment: `a` needs to be shared between the processes, you'll need to write `a` to shared memory

Comment: The fact that `a` is declared as a global variable is not enough?

Comment: Also, I would say that unless you need a specific set of numbers, use a generator rather than a list comp - it will have a lower "startup" time...

Comment: Global variables are still local to the process. Each process will have it's own copy of the global variable

Comment: @rdas Oh, right

Comment: Each process has its own memory-space, so you will need separate copies of `a` in each one. If `a` is large, the overhead of duplicating / copying it may make the overhead of using multiprocessing not worth it. Depending on what exactly `do_something()` does, it _might_ be worthwhile to use multithreading instead.

Comment: @martineau So if `a` is a generator as @Ed_Ward said, copying it for each process would not impact the performances right? In general, `imap(func, gen)`, `func`should be an "heavier" task than `gen`?

Comment: Would it make sens to let `gen` retrieve files from a remote server and then process them with `func`?

Comment: A prototype of the generator could be:
```
def gen(server):
 for file in server:
  if type(file) == PNG:
   yield file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers!

Comment: Atlas Zelos: Whether making `a` a generator would help or not would depend on what its contents really are — i.e. the actual source of the values. If it's simply because on some computation that could be start from any point, then yes, it would help.

Comment: But in my exemple, if a copy of `a` is made for each process, each process should loop through the same values therefore printing the same prime numbers?

Comment: Please look at my diagram to tell me if I understood: https://imgur.com/a/cKnFH3l

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your diagram. Suggest you watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk) from a Python conference to get some insights on concurrent programming.